# Merge files with the same prefix

Tags: concatenation

I have 324 files. The format of the file names is: 1.fa.abc.txt, 1.fa.de.txt, 1.fa.zen.txt and 2.fa.abc.txt, 2.fa.de.txt, 2.fa.zen.txt and 105.fa.abc.txt, 105.fa.de.txt,105.fa.zen.txt. All of these files are in the same folder. I want to merge all the files with the same prefix (the numbers in the prefix, in this case). Is there a quick way to do it?

Comment: how many prefixes do you have, a lot or just a few? if there are only a few you could do copy28*.*  result28.txt    copy29*.*  result29.txt  etc...

Comment: A lot. In this case from 1 to 108

Answer (score 0):

This code in a bat file will  merge all the files with the same prefix from 1 to 324, storing every merged file (from the prefix)  in a different result.txt:

```
 FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,324) DO copy %%G*.*  %%Gresult.txt
```